# HTML+JS -Tabla dinámica desde HTML1 con inputs hacia tabla en HTML2

Tags: javascript, html-tabla

tengo que realizar la carga de datos a una tabla desde 3 inputs, precionando 1 boton (JS) y que complete la tabla. Todo bien, solo que debo hacerlo siempre en el mismo HTML y la tabla la quiero tener en otro HTML. Es decir, que el usuario no puedo cargar los datos en la tabla, solo verlos. Como hago que funcione? o como los vinculo?

Modelo resumido:

HTML1:
input 1, 2 y 3
boton agregar ID "add"

HTML2:
tabla vacia con su ID "table"

JS:

```
window.onload = show;

let MiTabla = [];

document.querySelector("#btnAdd").addEventListener("click", add);

function add(){
let Uno = document.querySelector("#uno").value;
let Dos = document.querySelector("#dos").value;
let Tres = document.querySelector("#tres").value);  

let itemNuevo = {    
  uno: Uno,
  dos: Dos,
  tres: Tres,   
}

MiTabla.push(itemNuevo);
show();  
} 

function show(){
let TablaDom = document.querySelector("#table")
 TablaDom.innerHTML = '';
 for (let item of MiTabla) {
 TablaDom.innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+item.uno+"</td><td>"+item.dos+"</td><td>"+item.tres+"</td> 
 <td>"+" % " +item.dif+"</td></tr>"    
 }
}
```

Desde ya, muchas gracias

Comment: O sea, ¿quieres que desde un HTML con javascript tu generes una tabla y luego, que otro usuario o tu mismo abriendo otro HTML pueda ver esa tabla? Lo único que se me ocurre es que uses algun tipo de almacenamiento en el servidor para ello, usando scripts de PHP, ASP, o lo que sepas usar, ya sea con base de datos o escribiendo archivos en disco, como el propio HTML destino, pues solo con HTML y javascript no es posible.

Comment: Gracias! entiendo que no me deben estar pidiendo eso y yo la estoy complicando de mas. Me pidieron que de una tabla definida en HTML simple, se actualice dinámicamente desde JS pero no por un usuario, sino por un Admin, por ejemplo. Arbazo!

Comment: Dudo que te hayan pedido eso si no habeis tocado PHP y MySQL donde almacenar los datos de la tabla para que al conmutar entre el usuario y el admin se conserven los datos actualizados del admin. Se podria hacer solo con HTML y JS usando **localStorage** pero eso solo funciona si ambos usan el mismo navegador, por eso dudo que te lo hayan pedido así.  La pregunta no está clara y no se puede dar una respuesta tal como está, lo siento.

Answer (score 0):

Perdón, aclaro, el boton agregar tiene id=btnAdd, de todas formas el código funciona considerando la tabla junto con el botón y los input.
Gracias